# How to get a bit more help perhaps...?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am a little embarrassed to admit I have just spent more time fixing the dread issue:

```
**Syntax Error: Unexpected token <**
```

My mistake was that I had forgotten to add the following to my index.html:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
```

However I am including:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

Is there a way of configuring the angular2 dev version to emit more helpful info which would mean that I would get more helpful info regarding issues like this in dev?

Comment: Doesn't look line an Angular issue, more like one of other involved tools (I don't use TS with Angular myself).

Comment: my guess is you forgot to include a script like http.dev.js

Answer (score 1):

The `**Syntax Error: Unexpected token <**` comes from `SystemJS` trying to import the `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` or anything router related. Because you did not add the `router.dev.js` it won't be able to import it, and the webserver request will return a `404`. You will be able to see this error in your network console. The unexpected token `<` is actually the start tag of `<!DOCTYPE html>` from your `404` page