# How to use datepicker popup in angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to use date-picker popup in input control using angular 2, when do blur on input control, then date-picker pop should come like bootstrap datepicker, I want to do it in angular 2, please suggest me any reference of date-picker of Angular 2.

Answer (score 25):

I created my own datepicker-popup based on the [ng2-bootstrap datepicker](https://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/#/datepicker).

**HTML**

```
<my-datepicker [dateModel]="endDate" [label]="'Startdatum'" ></my-datepicker>
```

**Angular2-Component in TypeScript:**

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-datepicker',
    directives: [DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
      <label>{{label}}</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="dateModel" class="form-control"     (focus)="showPopup()" />
      <datepicker class="popup" *ngIf="showDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="dateModel" [showWeeks]="true" (ngModelChange)="hidePopup($event)" ></datepicker>
  `,
    styles: [`
    .popup {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      height: 251px;
    }
  `],
})
export class IsdDatepickerComponent {
    @Input()
    dateModel: Date;
    @Input()
    label: string;
    @Output()
    dateModelChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
    private showDatepicker: boolean = false;

    showPopup() {
        this.showDatepicker = true;
    }

    hidePopup(event) {
        this.showDatepicker = false;
        this.dateModel = event;
        this.dateModelChange.emit(event)
    }
}
```

Comment: Solid control, @Christoph.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for sharing

Comment: Could you please update the showWeeks attribute (it should be wrapped in [] brackets). Stackoverflow doesn't allow edits less than 6 characters :@

Comment: @AbuAbdullah Done.

Comment: @Christoph -- Superb ! .. Is there any way to hide the popup only when user click the date. Using the current code popup is closing when user click on date/month/year.

Comment: I have another issue - after the date is filled, the datepicker is not shown anymore, even though showDatepicker is correctly set to true via showPopup ... If I delete the input content it shows again ... any ideas?

Comment: Ok, I got it, if anybody else will have this problem - the click on the input field triggers a ngModelChange event which closes the popup. I had to compare the value in the input field with the previously set value and return  hidePopup when there was no change

Comment: @NidhinTT call hidePopup method on selectionDone event instead of modal change to do that

Comment: When i change months or years the popup disapear
i think you have to some contrtole to ngModelChange to check if on day is changed before to hide the popup

Comment: @ShyamShinde - Thankyou so much for your comment - I have been struggling with this for hours now!

Comment: ng2-bootstrap currently doesn't ship with components. I'm missing something

Answer (score 3):

Check out this date picker, it is highly configurable and its only dependency is moment.
https://github.com/vlio20/ng2-date-picker

Comment: The other one seemed buggy and this seems to work better, although it will require some css changes I think

Comment: Note that there is a material style class. And the css was built to be easy to style as you wish

Comment: I am struggling to find this css - I can see a less file, but it seems to be empty. Please let me know my my ignorance :)

Comment: Please refer to the documentation. You will find it there. Did you see the demo?

Comment: I can see in the css page of the demo, there are styles, such as: ".dp-calendar-nav-left[_ngcontent-ppw-0], .dp-calendar-nav-right[_ngcontent-ppw-0]{" which have been generated by css in an angular component. I guess I could just copy this css, remove the square brackets with their content from each line and then use this?

Comment: You can just overwrite them as an ordinary element

Answer (score 2):

Just use selectionDone inplace of ngModelChange event.
I used in my code:

```
    import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES} from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-datepicker',
    directives: [DATEPICKER_DIRECTIVES],
    template: `
      <label>{{label}}</label>
      <input [(ngModel)]="dateModel" class="form-control"     (focus)="showPopup()" />
      <datepicker class="popup" *ngIf="showDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="dateModel" [showWeeks]="true" (selectionDone)="hidePopup($event)" ></datepicker>
  `,
    styles: [`
    .popup {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      height: 251px;
    }
  `],
})
export class IsdDatepickerComponent {
    @Input()
    dateModel: Date;
    @Input()
    label: string;
    @Output()
    dateModelChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
    private showDatepicker: boolean = false;

    showPopup() {
        this.showDatepicker = true;
    }

    hidePopup(event) {
        this.showDatepicker = false;
        this.dateModel = event;
        this.dateModelChange.emit(event)
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be great to give credit to the author below who came up with most of part of this code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a new, excellent implementation of datepicker for Angular 2 based on Bootstrap 4: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker.

It is a fully native widget with forms integration and very flexible cusomization options.

Comment: The only thing with that is, it's for bootstrap 4. I also noticed that when you click outside the datepicker, it does not automatically close the datepicker. Though I keep an eye on it, looks very interesting, next to ng2-bootstrap (has an bootstrap3/4 version).

Comment: Bootstrap 4 is still alpha, while I look forward to it being released this spring I wouldn't recommend it for most projects.

Answer (score 1):

this is my implementation based on Christophs answer. i am using two way binding. component emits date as a string yyyy-mm-dd for saving on server. but it shows date inside component as a string dd-mm-yyyy . its convinient for cross browser displaying

```
 <datepicker-popup [(dateModel)]="serverDate"></datepicker-popup>
```

ts:

```
import {Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DatePickerComponent} from 'ng2-bootstrap/datepicker';

@Component({
selector: 'datepicker-popup',
template: `
  <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="_dateModel" class="form-control" (click)="openPopup()">
  <datepicker class="popup"
      [hidden]="!showPopup"
      [(ngModel)]="dateModelObj"
      [showWeeks]="true"
      (ngModelChange)="closePopup($event)" >
  </datepicker>


 `,
    styles: [`
    .popup {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      height: 251px;
    }
  `],
})
export class DatepickerPopupComponent implements OnInit{
    @Input() dateModel: string;
    @Output()  dateModelChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();
    showPopup: boolean = false;
    _dateModel: string;
    dateModelObj: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.dateModelObj = new Date(this.dateModel)
}

openPopup() {
    this.showPopup = true;
}

closePopup(event) {
    this.showPopup = false;
    this._dateModel = this.DDMMYYYY(event);
    this.dateModelChange.emit(this.YYYYMMDD(event))
}

YYYYMMDD(date):string {
    if (!date) return null;
    return date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
};

DDMMYYYY(date):string {
    if (!date) return null;
    return date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
};
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this,
Pre requirments `ng2-bootstrap`

import date picker module in your app module

```
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap';
```

app-datepicker

```
<app-datepicker name="date" [(ngModel)]="driver.dateOfBirth" [placeholder]="'Date of Birth'" [dateFormat]="'dd-MM-yyyy'" ngDefaultControl required></app-datepicker>
```

datepicker.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-datepicker',
    templateUrl: './datepicker.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./datepicker.component.css']
})

    export class DatepickerComponent {
        public inputHeight: String;

        @ViewChild('tasknote') input: ElementRef;
        @Input()
        ngModel: String;
        @Input()
        label: string;
        @Input()
        dateFormat: string;
        @Input()
        placeholder: string;
        @Output()
        ngModelChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter();

        private showDatepicker: boolean = false;

        constructor(public element: ElementRef) {
        }

        showPopup(element) {
            this.inputHeight = this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('input').getBoundingClientRect().height + 'px';
            this.showDatepicker = true;
        }

        hidePopup(event) {
            this.showDatepicker = false;
            if (event) {
                var date = new DatePipe('en-us').transform(event, this.dateFormat || 'dd/MM/yyyy');
                this.ngModel = date;
                this.ngModelChange.emit(date);
            }
        }
    }
```

datepicker.component.html

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <label [ngClass]="{'hide': !label}">{{label}}</label>
    <input #tasknote name="date-picker" [(ngModel)]="ngModel" (focus)="showPopup($elem)" placeholder="{{placeholder}}" required/>
    <datepicker class="popup" [ngClass]="{'hide': !showDatepicker}" [(ngModel)]="date" [showWeeks]="true" (selectionDone)="hidePopup($event)"
        [ngStyle]="{'bottom': inputHeight}"></datepicker>
</div>
```

datepicker.component.css

```
.popup {
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-radius: 3px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      height: 251px;
      color: #000;
      right: 0px;
    }
.hide {
     display:none;
}
```

Answer (score -7):

You could use the ng2-boostrap project that provides a date picker component:

```
<datepicker [(ngModel)]="date" showWeeks="true"></datepicker>
```

See the project page:

- https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap

See this question for the way to configure ng2-bootstrap (and the moment library) within the SystemJS configuration:

- [integrate bootstrap module and ng2-select module to angular2 5min quickstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865644/integrate-bootstrap-module-and-ng2-select-module-to-angular2-5min-quickstart/35866957#35866957)

Comment: This doesn't work out of the box yet with ng2-bootstrap. (Datepicker as popup)

Comment: @lexith is correct ng2-bootstrap is not yet working.

Comment: I confirm ng2-bootstrap doesn't work on Angular2 rc5, it keeps throwing weird error messages.

Comment: Although you can get the ng2-bootstrap DatePicker to work like a popup, I've found the ng2-bootstrap project to be somewhat unstable and lacking in the area of documentation.

Comment: the ng2-bootstrap datepickers still doesnt have a popup version, only inline