# Angular 2 with bootstrap JS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular

I've been trying to use the progressbar animation of the powerful bootstrap library I'm used to, which worked great with Angular 1, but sadly not working with Angular 2.

My Angular 2 HTML:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
  aria-valuenow="{{enemy.HP}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="{{enemy.HP}}" style="width:{{(enemy.HP/100)*100}}%">
      {{enemy.HP}} HP
  </div>
</div>
```

Caused this error:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'aria-valuenow' since it isn't a known native property ("iv class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
  [ERROR ->]aria-valuenow="{{enemy.HP}}" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="{{enemy.HP}}" style="width:{{(enemy.HP/"): AppComponent@22:2
Can't bind to 'aria-valuemax' since it isn't a known native property ("r progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
  aria-valuenow="{{enemy.HP}}" aria-valuemin="0" [ERROR ->]aria-valuemax="{{enemy.HP}}" style="width:{{(enemy.HP/100)*100}}%">
      {{enemy.HP}} HP
  </div>
"): AppComponent@22:49
```

If anyone can share an alternative way to use the bootstrap progressbar, I will appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ng2-bootstrap and its progress bar component. See the corresponding documentation:

- http://valor-software.com/ng2-bootstrap/.

Here is a sample from the documentation:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <progressbar value="55"></progressbar>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <progressbar class="progress-striped" value="22" 
                 type="warning">22%</progressbar>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <progressbar class="progress-striped active"
                 max="200" value="166" type="danger"><i>166 / 200</i>
    </progressbar>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already loooked up for it but had terrible time installing it, somehow I get `GET http://localhost:3000/ng2-bootstrap 404 (Not Found)`, after installing it with `npm install --save ng2-bootstrap`, added this: `import {
  Ng2BootstrapConfig, Ng2BootstrapTheme, PROGRESSBAR_DIRECTIVES
} from '../../../ng2-bootstrap';`, and the directives `directives: [PROGRESSBAR_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES],`

Comment: Yes, it's not so obvious. See this question for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35865644/integrate-bootstrap-module-and-ng2-select-module-to-angular2-5min-quickstart/35866957#35866957. There are some configurations in SystemJS to do. Then you can import components like this: `import { Ng2BootstrapConfig, Ng2BootstrapTheme, PROGRESSBAR_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';`

Comment: Updated my SystemJS, but the same error appears. it is not the same error as shown in the question above. I've been trying to google my error, but all solution didn't work for me

Answer (score 9):

The binding for attributes like `aria-valuenow` should look like `[attr.aria-valuenow]` (see more details in [Angular 2 docs: Attribute, class, and style bindings](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#other-bindings)). Double curly braces will go away as well.

The `width` in the `style` attribute should look like `[style.width]` (details [Angular 2 docs: NgStyle](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngStyle))

So your snippet will look like this:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar"
  [attr.aria-valuenow]="enemy.HP" aria-valuemin="0" [attr.aria-valuemax]="enemy.HP" [style.width]="(enemy.HP/100)*100 + '%'">
      {{enemy.HP}} HP
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one works well for me. This is my template:
`<div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" attr.aria-valuenow="{{ percentage }}" aria-valuemin="0"
            aria-valuemax="100" [style.width]="percentage + '%'"></div>
    </div>`